# Is there a book on glibc?

Tags: c, glibc

Everything in linux is built on top of it,

but reading its source code directly is too tough for me.

Is there a good book on it?

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but not everyone in the Linux ecosystem uses glibc; [Alpine Linux](http://alpinelinux.org) uses [musl](http://www.musl-libc.org), and Android uses bionic. µClibc is also popular in embedded.

Answer (score 9):

[GLIBC User Manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/index.html) would be a good start.

Comment: Also the man pages in sections 2,3, and 7.